# asp.net core multiple apps on nginx

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core

I have been working to get a couple asp.net core webapps running on EC2 ubuntu instance using nginx and supervisor.  I am successful in running one app at a time and by simply swapping my port in my nginx setting and reloading I can swap between the running .netcore apps running on 5000 and 5001.  I cannot seem to figure out the nginx settings to make them both work at a path, ie: hostname/app1, hostname/app2.

Here is my Nginx Config.  Could anyone point to something I have done wrong? My supervisor is running both apps I can verify that by looking at the logs and also changing the port in the default location "/".

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

#    location / {
#            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
#            proxy_http_version 1.1;
#            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
#            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
#            proxy_set_header Host $host;
#            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
#    }


    location /app1 {
            rewrite ^/app1(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /app2{
            rewrite ^/app2(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I do not have a default route simple because I don't have anything to put there yet.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like the solution was trailing slashes on the location and proxypass

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

#    location / {
#            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
#            proxy_http_version 1.1;
#            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
#            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
#            proxy_set_header Host $host;
#            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
#    }


    location /app1/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /app2/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5001/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work because it responds only on first request than .net core apps are not able to resolve routes like localhost/app1.....